# Does the delegate's stake change their vote's weight?

Tags: governance

Since users who don't have enough tokens to participate in the governance process can delegate their stake to someone who can participate, does each delegate's vote have a different weight? Or is it the case that a vote is just a vote no matter how many delegators you have?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every delegation contributes to the number of votes a baker represents, where each vote is equivalent to 8000ꜩ (a roll).

Let's imagine I hold 24000ꜩ, and I delegate them to a baker. My delegation would represent 3 rolls/votes after 7 cycles if I'm not mistaken.

[More Info](https://www.tezosagora.org/learn#an-introduction-to-tezos-governance)

Comment: Got it - thank you for clarifying!